# How to call different project targets at runtime not a different app in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an application where I want to have some way where I will be able to run only selected project target at run time, maybe on click of a button. But I am not able to get the idea of how to link these targets and call the appropriate one at run time.

Below are some screenshots of my project:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Here, I have created multiple project in a single one. But getting confused about how to connect these.

What I want is, for example, if I click on button 1 on login page, then only first project should run and similarly, if I click on button 2 , then only second project should run, and so on.

Comment: are you talking about to do this from xcode or from running app?

Comment: no , because you need to select manually targets, once application runs its compile resources for only one project.

Comment: right. but could you explain more in detail then what are you trying to do.

Comment: i want this when i run the app @Ellen

Comment: Means i have two different types of projects, and i want the user to select the type of app he wants to run. For eg, If he selects country 1, then the project for first country must run, and if he select country 2 , then project for second country must run. All this should be happening at run time. How can we  achieve this?

Comment: @Ellen Actually I created multiple project in one single project. When I run app first screen will be same for all when I click on button it will change project target and rest file will call from that project. Is it is possible because creating multiple project is possible.

Comment: @JoshCaswell this question is not duplicate because I am trying to open different project not a different app. App must be same and different project will open on button click. How to do this??

Comment: There's no project or target after you build and install. You have one app. Anything you want to do needs to be in that one app. Or it can be in a completely separate app that is also installed on the device. What I linked you to is how you do the latter, because that's the only way to do exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Is it is possible to change project target on button click.

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Can you Please tell me other way how to achieve this thing without creating multiple app.Is there is an way to call different target view controller not a whole target.

Comment: [What is a "target", in plain language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637435/xcode-what-is-a-target-and-scheme-in-plain-language) [What are "targets" in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056213/xcode-targets)

Comment: You can not load any framework/code at run time which is not linked in your target as per Apple Guidelines. You can have your assets etc as ondemand resource content & can download as per your requirements.https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one target app, go to `set the active schema menu` (next to the stop build target) and choose the respective target app and run.

Comment: ok. But i want this to be happening after i run the app , and allow the user to select the appropriate project which he wants to run. Is this possible?? If yes, then how. If no, then is there any alternate to it?